# How can Spring RestTemplate deal with response content-type "text/csv; charset=utf-8-sig" sent by a third party service?

Tags: spring, content-type, resttemplate

With RestTemplate, I post a request to a third party service whose response content-type is *text/csv; charset=utf-8-sig*
When parsing the response, Spring rejects it with the following message :

```
Invalid mime type "text/csv; charset=utf-8-sig": unsupported charset 'utf-8-sig'
```

I don't know what utf-8-sig means, but I have no other choices but adapt to the third party service.
Below is the code I use :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
                .builder("form-data").name("data")
                .filename(fichierInput.get().getName()).build();
fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());
HttpEntity<byte[]> fileEntity = 
                         new HttpEntity<>(content.getBytes(), fileMap);
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("data", fileEntity);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
try {
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate
             .exchange(this.applicationProperties.getGeoloc().getUrl(),
                       HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, byte[].class);
    log.debug("retour de geoloc : {} ", response.getBody());
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My question is : Do I have a way to tell Spring not to read this header but instead take the request body "as-is" ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by creating a custom interceptor to modify the headers of the response => [example here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor)

Answer (score 0):

Added this in the header:

```
headerMap.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Also make sure you have latest jackson core included, If you are using gradle use:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.11.0.rc1'
```